# Unable concate NULL value in SQL using CONCAT, COALESCE and ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a query with multiple joins where I want to combine records from two columns into one. If one column is empty then I want to show one column value as result. I tried with `CONCAT`, `COALEASE` and `ISNULL` but no luck. What am I missing here?

My objective is, create one column which has combination of `s.Script AS Original` and `FromAnotherTable` from query. Below query runs but throws `Invalid column name 'Original'` and `Invalid column name 'FromAnotherTable'`. when I try to use `CONCAT`, `COALEASE` or `ISNULL` .

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Name AS CallCenter,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
       d.DNIS,
       s.ScriptId,
      s.Script AS Original,
      (
          SELECT TOP 5 CCSL.Line+'; ' 
          FROM CallCenterScriptLine CCSL
          WHERE CCSL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
          ORDER BY ScriptLineId FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS FromAnotherTable,
         --CONCAT(s.Script, SELECT TOP 5 CCSL.Line+'; ' FROM dbo.CallCenterScriptLine ccsl WHERE ccsl.ScriptId = s.ScriptId ORDER BY ccsl.ScriptLineId xml path(''))
         --CONCAT(Original, FromAnotherTable) AS Option1,
         --COALESCE(Original, '') + FromAnotherTable AS Option2,
         --ISNULL(Original, '') + FromAnotherTable AS Option3,,
       r.UnitName AS Store,
       r.UnitNumber
FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNISRestaurant ccd WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccd.CallCenterDNISId = d.CallCenterDNISId
     INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurant r WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.RestaurantID = ccd.CallCenterRestaurantId
WHERE c.Id = 5
      AND (1 = 1)
      AND (s.IsDeleted = 0 OR s.IsDeleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY DNIS ASC;
```

**Output:**
[image]

**This works:**

```
DECLARE @Column1 VARCHAR(50) = 'Foo',
        @Column2 VARCHAR(50) = NULL;

SELECT CONCAT(@Column1,@Column2);
SELECT COALESCE(@Column2, '') + @Column1
SELECT ISNULL(@Column2, '') + @Column1
```

So I am not sure what I am missing in my original query.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to achive but I have looked at the code and I have a question: I see that you are calculating column Script with XML clause, and two rows in SELECT below you are refering to the column Script. Are you doing it?

Comment: Be careful using that nolock hint all over the place. It is far more sinister than most people realize. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz So basically, I was reading form one table only and now I am reading from two. Only reason for using XML is to combine multiple line in one. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Why are you trying to concatenate `s.Script +'; ', Script`?    What do you think is the difference between `s.Script` and `Script`?   Your aliased subquery?   Trying giving it a different name to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Look at row 3 in the results you are getting.   In your concatenated columns (Option1, 2, 3) you are getting the first script column twice.  Not the first one + the second one like you expect.

The reason is because you've aliased your subquery "script" which is the same name as another column in your query, which makes it ambiguous.

Change the alias of the subquery and the problem should go away.   I'm frankly surprised your query didn't raise an error.

EDIT:   You can't use a column alias in another column's definition in the same level of the query.   In other words, you can't do this:

```
SELECT 
  SomeColumn AS A
, (Subquery that returns a column) AS B
, A + B  --this is not allowed
FROM ...
```

You can either create a CTE that returns the aliased columns and then concatenate them in the main query that selects from the CTE, or you have to use the original sources of the aliases, like so:

```
SELECT 
  SomeColumn AS A
, (Subquery that returns a column) AS B
, SomeColumn  + (Subquery that returns a column)  --this is fine
FROM ...
```

Comment: Make sense. If I name `s.Script AS Original` and my subquery as `FromAnotherTable` or any other name then I can't use `CONCAT`. It gives me invalid column name error on my aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I took another approach where instead on creating separate column, I used `ISNULL` in my `subQuery` which returns my desired result.

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Name AS CallCenter,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) Name,
       d.DNIS,
       s.ScriptId,
      s.Script AS Original,
      (
          SELECT TOP 5 ISNULL(CCSL.Line, '')+'; ' + ISNULL(s.Script, '')
          FROM CallCenterScriptLine CCSL
          WHERE CCSL.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
          ORDER BY ScriptLineId FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS FromAnotherTable,
       r.UnitName AS Store,
       r.UnitNumber
FROM CallCenterScript s WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNIS d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.ScriptId = s.ScriptId
     INNER JOIN CallCenter c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = s.CallCenterId
     INNER JOIN CallCenterDNISRestaurant ccd WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccd.CallCenterDNISId = d.CallCenterDNISId
     INNER JOIN dbo.Restaurant r WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.RestaurantID = ccd.CallCenterRestaurantId
WHERE c.Id = 5
      AND (1 = 1)
      AND (s.IsDeleted = 0 OR s.IsDeleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY DNIS ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example using table variables.

Instead of using a subquery for a field, it uses a CROSS APPLY.

And CONCAT in combination with STUFF is used to glue the strings together.

```
declare @Foo table (fooID int identity(1,1) primary key, Script varchar(30));
declare @Bar table (barID int identity(1,1) primary key, fooID int, Line varchar(30));

insert into @Foo (Script) values 
('Test1'),('Test2'),(NULL);

insert into @Bar (fooID, Line) values 
(1,'X'),(1,'Y'),(2,NULL),(3,'X'),(3,'Y');

select  
 f.fooID, 
 f.Script,
 x.Lines,
 CONCAT(Script+'; ', STUFF(x.Lines,1,2,''))  as NewScript
from @Foo f
cross apply (
    select '; '+b.Line
    from @Bar b
    where b.fooID = f.fooID 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) x(Lines)
```

Result:

```
fooID Script  Lines   NewScript
----- ------- ------- -----------
1     Test1   ; X; Y  Test1; X; Y
2     Test2   NULL    Test2; 
3     NULL    ; X; Y  X; Y
```